# Grizzly REST - POSTs are always 404

Tags: java, rest, jersey, grizzly

In my endpoint, I have some methods with `@GET` and some methods with `@POST`. `@GET`s are working fine, but `@POST`s always return `404`.

Here is some part from the endpoint's interface:

```
public interface TestEndpoint {

    @GET
    @Path("/ping")
    Response ping();

    @POST
    @Path("/weather/{iata}/{pointType}")
    Response updateWeather(@PathParam("iata") String iataCode,
                           @PathParam("pointType") String pointType,
                           String datapointJson);

    @POST
    @Path("/airport/{iata}/{lat}/{long}")
    Response addAirport(@PathParam("iata") String iata,
                        @PathParam("lat") String latString,
                        @PathParam("long") String longString);

    @GET
    @Path("/exit")
    Response exit();
}
```

Here is the server initialization part:

```
public class TestServer {

    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://localhost:9090/";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            final ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig();
            resourceConfig.register(TestEndpointImpl.class);

            HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(BASE_URL), resourceConfig, false);
            Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
                server.shutdownNow();
            }));

            HttpServerProbe probe = new HttpServerProbe.Adapter() {
                public void onRequestReceiveEvent(HttpServerFilter filter, Connection connection, Request request) {
                    System.out.println(request.getRequestURI());
                }
            };
            server.getServerConfiguration().getMonitoringConfig().getWebServerConfig().addProbes(probe);

            server.start();
            Thread.currentThread().join();
            server.shutdown();
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TestServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

where, `TestEndpointImpl` is an implementation of `TestEndpoint` (as the name implies) with class-level annotation `@Path("/collect")`.

When I perform GET requests, it works fine. But POSTs are problematic. Corresponding methods are not called.

As a side note, `probe` prints both GET and POST requests as expected, so I am sure that requests reach the server and paths are ok.

Is there any suggestion?

**EDIT:** Some snippet from the implementation:

```
@Path("/collect")
public class TestEndpointImpl implements TestEndpoint {

    ...

    @Override
    public Response updateWeather(@PathParam("iata") String iataCode, @PathParam("pointType") String pointType,
            String datapointJson) {
        System.out.println("TRACE: " + datapointJson);
        // do something and return a Response
    }

    ...

}
```

The registered probe prints `/collect/weather/BOS/wind`, but `updateWeather` is not called.

Comment: Copy the `@POST` and the `@Path` annotations to the method implementation. It should do the trick.

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin But methods with ``@GET`` are working, without such annotations in the implementation.

Comment: Yes, it started to work, but how?

Comment: I'm writing an answer for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short answer

Copy the [`@POST`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/POST.html) and the [`@Path`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Path.html) annotations to the method implementation. It will do the trick.

### Long answer

The section regarding *annotation inheritance* of the [JAX-RS 2.0](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxrs-2_0-fr-eval-spec/jsr339-jaxrs-2.0-final-spec.pdf) specification (the specification which Jersey is the reference implementation) is pretty clear. See the quote below:

> **3.6 Annotation Inheritance**
>
> JAX-RS annotations may be used on the methods and method parameters of a super-class or an implemented interface. Such annotations are inherited by a corresponding sub-class or implementation class method provided that the method and its parameters do not have any JAX-RS annotations of their own. Annotations on a super-class take precedence over those on an implemented interface. The precedence over conflicting annotations defined in multiple implemented interfaces is implementation specific. Note that inheritance of class or interface annotations is not supported.
>
> If a subclass or implementation method has any JAX-RS annotations then *all* of the annotations on the superclass or interface method are ignored. E.g.:
>
> ```java
> public interface ReadOnlyAtomFeed {
>
>     @GET 
>     @Produces("application/atom+xml")
>     Feed getFeed();
> }
> ```
>
> ```java
> @Path("feed")
> public class ActivityLog implements ReadOnlyAtomFeed {
>
>     public Feed getFeed() {...}
> }
> ```
>
> In the above, `ActivityLog.getFeed` inherits the `@GET` and `@Produces` annotations from the interface. Conversely:
>
> ```java
> @Path("feed")
> public class ActivityLog implements ReadOnlyAtomFeed {
>
>     @Produces("application/atom+xml")
>     public Feed getFeed() {...}
> }
> ```
>
> In the above, the `@GET` annotation on `ReadOnlyAtomFeed.getFeed` is not inherited by `ActivityLog.getFeed` and it would require its own request method designator since it redefines the `@Produces` annotation.
>
> For consistency with other Java EE specifications, it is recommended to always repeat annotations instead of relying on annotation inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

That can also happen if the url is not in the correct format; for example you could have sent a request without the correct path parameters.

Comment: The printed URI from the probe is ``/collect/weather/BOS/wind``, so it should match ``updateWeather``'s path. Right?